# How to enable Design Ruler on VS.NET winform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When Creating and Adjusting Controls on Winforms visual studio has its intellisense ruler so you can Arrange all controls symetrically.

Now My Problem is i dont know how to Enable this again in VS.Where can i see the option to enable that tools again.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

You can use either **SnapLines** or **SnapToGrid** by changing settings here:

Tools -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> General -> Layout Mode (and ShowGrid, SnapToGrid)

*Note, you'll need to close and reopen the designer for the changes to take effect.*

Or, you can align controls by selecting the ones you wish to align and using **alignment functions on the Layout toolbar**. To display the Layout toolbar, right-click on an empty area of your toolbar (you should then see a long list of available toolbars), and check the checkbox for "Layout".

Comment: Thanks Sir...Layout is not Check on my toolbars.